# How to know the reasons why a query fails

Tags: database, api

Let’s suppose a multi-tenant application with the following tables:

```
person (tenant_id, id, status, name, company_id)
company (tenant_id, id, name)
```

When updating a person entry, the following constraints apply:

- `company_id` must exist and `tenant_id` must match
- `status` must be valid

I’m currently using a single query that takes into account all the constraints:

```sql
UPDATE person 
SET person.company_id = 100
WHERE person.tenant_id = 'A'
 AND person.id = 1
 AND person.status = 10
 AND EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM company WHERE company.tenant_id='A' and company.id=100)
```

The ouput of the query indicates how many rows were updated.

In the case where no row is updated, I would like to know the root cause. Is It because:

- the `id` (which is my primary key in my case) does NOT exist.
- the `id` DOES exist but the `status` is not correct.
- the `company_id` does NOT exist.

It would allow me to return an appropriate error message.

Do you think it is better to :

### Make separate queries beforehand

1. Select the entry without any constraints except the primary key.

```sql
SELECT id, status, name FROM person WHERE tenant_id = 'A' AND id = 1
```

If no entry is found, I can return a 404 right away.

If an entry is found, I can check whether the `status` is valid. If it is not valid, I can return an error message.

2. Make sure the `company` object exists

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM company WHERE tenant_id = 'A' AND id = 100
```

If it does not exist, I can return an error message.

If it does, I can try to make the update.

3. Update

Run the initial query including all the constraints because data may have been changed since Step 1.

*Pros:* None?

*Cons:* Several DB calls, Slower process, Data can be changed during the process.

### Run the whole query first and try to find the reason afterwards

Here, I try to be optimistic and run the initial query right away considering that data is valid most of the time.

I make additional queries (the same as above) to know the root cause only if data is not valid.

Data might still change between the time I run the initial query and the time of the last query.

*Pros:* Faster when data is valid

*Cons:* Several DB calls in case of error, Data can be changed during the process.

### Use stored procedure

That would solve the "data change" issue but I would like to avoid using stored procedure.

*Pros:* Make a single DB call

*Cons:* DB Workload

To be very specific, i'm running this application with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
UPDATE person 
    SET person.company_id = 100
    WHERE person.tenant_id = 'A'
     AND person.id = 1
     AND person.status = 10
     AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM company WHERE company.tenant_id='A' and company.id=100)
```

Comment: Although you're right about the SQL syntax, it does not answer the question. I would like to know how to deal with queries that have several constraints and find a way to know which one makes them fail.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough in that it doesn't tell what you mean by "doesn't succeed".  No rows found to update might be regarded by you as "hasn't succeeded" but technically, SQL will have done its job successfully and issue only a warning for this.  Second reason why your question is not clear enough is that you don't spell out in great detail what kind of error messages you think would be "appropriate".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my initial post hoping it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

From a *performance* point of view it is most likely that "Run the whole query first and try to find the reason afterwards" is your best option, where "afterwards" means "only in the case when it turns out no rows were updated".

This is based on an assumption that such "failures" will be relatively rare, and this assumption is itself based on the assumption that the selection criteria for identifying the row to be updated will be established relatively recently.  (If it's a batch of data 5 days old, things might be slightly different.)

(And I might also want to add that from a *functionality* point of view it is relatively uncommon to try and get error messages to the level of precision you seem to be after, the reason being that it always turns out to be way trickier and intricate to get "right" than you probably imagine.)